# Reading XML File - reading a child node which has any number of subnodes

Tags: c#, xml

So I'm currentlty trying to parse an XML file which looks like so:

```
<employees>
    <employee>
     <id>1</id>
         <projects>
            <projectID>7</projectID>
            <projectID>3</projectID>
         </projects>
    </employee>
    <employee>
     <id>2</id>
         <projects>
            <projectID>4</projectID>
         </projects>
    </employee>
</employees>
```

I'm trying to read in each employee and any number of projects which appear. The Employee object is a string and list(int).

Currently I have:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlNodeList xmlNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/employees/employee");
        foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xmlNodes)
        {
            string id;
            List<int> projects = new List<int>();

            id = xmlNode.SelectSingleNode("id").InnerText;

            //this is the bit. What I have works but it feels like it could
            //be majorly refined. Is there a better way to construct the foreach below?

            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlNode.ChildNodes.Item(1)) 
            //index 1 is the projects node
            {
                projects.Add(int.Parse(node.InnerText));
            }

            //

            Employee e = new Employee(id, projects);
            e.Add(e);
        }
```

If the XML file itself is an issue it can be changed to accomodate the parsing.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to use XmlDocument? Using LINQ to XML (XDocument etc) normally makes things simpler.

Comment: What do you want to refine? Are there any performance issues or you don't like how the code looks now?

Comment: if you are using XMLDocument, you can use Enumerator and look through each node. For example - XmlNodeList xmlNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("/employees/employee");IEnumerator enumList = doc.GetEnumerator() and then loop through it

Comment: -1 What is the meaning of deleting the previous one and asking the same thing again? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22154081/parsing-xml-child-node-that-has-subnodes-c-sharp At least, you could have commented something.

Comment: @L.B wanted to edit some stuff, didn't realise there was an edit button :) realised after I had created the new post/deleted the old one. To answer other comments, I am unfamilliar with the Linq library and I wanted to refine the second foreach loop in the code :) It seems to me that I could be over-complicating things :)

Comment: @user1795294 But you didn't post an edited one. Exactly the same (the only change is the indentation)

Comment: @L.B which is what I wanted to change :) sorry for the confusion :)

Comment: @user1795294 Do you think other people's time is not important? I posted an answer and you deleted it without commeting anything. It could be not what you have expected but I find it, say, rude.. (BTW: It worked very well with your sampel xml)

Comment: @L.B Duly noted. Once again, sorry for any offence and/or time wastage caused by my simple mis-understanding :)

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier with LINQ to XML:

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(path);
var employees = (from e in xDoc.Root.Elements("employee")
                 let projects = e.Element("projects")
                                 .Elements("projectID")
                                 .Select(p => (int)p)
                                 .ToList()
                 let id = (string)e.Element("id")
                 select new Employee(id, projects)).ToList();
```

You need `using System.Linq` and `using System.Xml.Linq` to make it work.

Comment: With this I seem to be getting an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" exception being thrown. Could this be because Employee is not set or instantiated? Edit: never mind, I was using the wrong thing where "projects" should have been! Thanks :)

Comment: I having an issue of adding every new instance of supervisor made to a list.